# how to rewrite vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/js/theme.js in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to edit something about vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/js/theme.js in magento2,
how to rewrite this file?anyone can help me? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should work the same way as editing and create a new frontend theme, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html You should create the override of the theme in your app/ folder and go from there. Check how it is for app/design/frontend part and replicate with adminhtml and see from there.